# How can I combine back two splited dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which I sliced into two and performed function simultaneously and found the values1 separately. Now, I want to combine these two data frame back together in same continuously manner.

**For example:**

```
df1 = index  Values1
      0        a
      1        b
      2        c
      3        d
      9        i
      10       j

 df2 = index  Values1
       4        f
       5        g
       6        h
       7        n
       8        m
```

Result that I want is:

```
df3 = index Values1
      0        a      
      1        b      
      2        c      
      3        d       
      4        f
      5        g
      6        h
      7        n
      8        m
      9        i
      10       j
```

I thank you for your time and help.

Comment: ``pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(subset='index')``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6}, 
                  'value1': {0: 'a', 1:'c', 2:'e', 3:'g'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7}, 
                  'value1': {0: 'b', 1:'d', 2:'f', 3:'h'}})

df3 = df1.append(df2).sort_values('index').set_index('index')
df3
```

output:

[image]

Comment: You can also set 'index' column as index after concatenation.

`df3 = df1.append(df2).sort_values('index').set_index('index')`

Comment: @Cyruseption, thanks, I edit code block as you say :)))